# Calculate subject-level Mean and SD and mark values that are +/-3SD as missing in a new variable

Tags: r

I have a data frame composed of hundreds of subjects where each subject has x number of trials on a behavioral task that measures reaction time (rt). I need to mark rt as missing (i.e, "NA") when the rt is +/-3 standard deviations (SD) above and below the subject mean. Here is a sample data frame:

```
rt <- runif(60, 300, 900)
id <- rep(1:3,each=20)
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(rt,id))
```

I can calculate mean and sd for each subject, but I do not know how to compare each subjects' value of +/-3SD to the original rt variable and create a new rt variable with those values that are +/-3SD as missing. I am not sure if I should be trying to write a for loop or use an apply function. Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(newrt = ifelse(abs(rt - mean(rt)) >= 3 * sd(rt), NA, rt))
```

In the data you provided, there are no values that fit this description, but the code should work.

Answer (score 2):

```
means<-tapply(df$rt,df$id,FUN=mean)
sds<-tapply(df$rt,df$id,FUN=sd)
newrt<-ifelse(abs(df$rt-means[df$id])/sds[df$id]>=3,NA,df$rt)
```

Means and sds will contain the means and standard deviations for each id.

`means[df$id]` will repeat each mean according to the id of that subject, so that `df$rt-means[df$id]` will give the difference for each subject from the subject mean, and abs acts on each element of that, and the division acts element by element, so that

```
abs(df$rt-means[df$id])/sds[df$id]
```

results in a vector containing the number of standard deviations that each subject differs from its mean, and comparing to 3, we get a true or false vector telling if a subject differs at least 3 standard deviations or not.  Finally, the ifelse function will select a value of NA for each one that differs by at least 3 sd, or the actual value of the measurement otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

We could use `data.table` and assign (`:=`) in place (which would be more efficient).  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), create "newrt" as a copy of "rt", based on the TRUE values got from the logical condition in `i`, grouped by "id", we assign "new_rt" values to `NA`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, newrt := rt][abs(rt-mean(rt)) >= 3*sd(rt),
                                    newrt := NA_real_ ,id]
```

Comment: Doesn't the following do the same? `setDT(df)[abs(rt-mean(rt)) >= sd(rt)*1.5, rt:=NA, by=id]`

Comment: @mtoto Yes, it does the same.  But, it appears that the OP wanted the results in a new column, so I initialized `newrt`